# How to use a React Component as a substitute to a keycloak ftl template?

Tags: reactjs, keycloak

In Keycloak, we can create custom themes. Usually, we copy an existing theme and then style it our own way. We just modify CSS.

But what if I want a slightly different structure? Or add more elements? Then I should modify an ftl template, right?
How do I make sense of it? How to know what to remove? What if I am removing something important? Any recommended tutorials? Any way to render javascript/React instead of an ftl template?

Comment: use keycloakify https://docs.keycloakify.dev